# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

I have such a mistake:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Error in this place:

```
swal.getContent().querySelector('strong').textContent = swal.getTimerLeft()
```

How can I fix it?

Full code:

```
    let timerInterval
    swal({
      title: 'Auto close alert!',
      html: 'I will close in <strong></strong> seconds.',
      timer: 2000,
      onOpen: () => {
        swal.showLoading()
        timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
          swal.getContent().querySelector('strong')
            .textContent = swal.getTimerLeft()
        }, 100)
      },
      onClose: () => {
        clearInterval(timerInterval)
      }
    }).then((result) => {
      if (
        // Read more about handling dismissals
        result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer
      ) {
        console.log('I was closed by the timer')
      }
    })
```

Comment: `function getTimerLeft(): number | null;` https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/378016581407da535ec6b95a7fb05030121c0f45/sweetalert2.d.ts#L232

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Node.textContent` is a string and `swal.getTimerLeft()` does not return a string.

To fix this, use `Number.prototype.toString()`:

```js
Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('strong').textContent = swal.getTimerLeft().toString();
```

Comment: you can use an abreviated textContent='' +swal.getTimerLeft():two simple quotes + a number

Answer (score 1):

The Issue is  `swal.getTimerLeft()` does not return a string

To fix this issue use simply `toString()` method below like this.

```
         {
            Swal.showLoading();
            const b = Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector("b");
            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
              b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft().toString();
            }, 500);
         }
```